# I am interested in an abandoned patent application

Tags: patent-applications

I have a very similar product to a product that was disclosed in an abandoned patent application.

Can I improve and add new changes to that application thereby providing new claims to the patent application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes provided your changes are novel and not obvious over prior art. you might get new patent but you can't benefit from this patent priority or filing date. Alternatively you can contact inventor and sell him your idea he might be interested in CIP of reference patent.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can only patent what *you* invent. Of course, you can buy patent rights from someone who has them. If the original applicant could legitamtly revive the application and get a patent, he could sell it to you.

Comment: i think if changes are novel and not obvious he might get new claims. with new patent application.